# Finding data to work on pandas for data analysis with Python

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory, analysis

I am trying to learn data analysis with Python and working with Pandas. Is there anyone to help me to find open data two work on. I will try to use data for data analysis with python on google colab. So I need csv files to work on it. I would be happy ıf you can direct me abour it

Comment: You'll find plenty of datasets and notebooks to learn from on Kaggle. https://www.kaggle.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get datasets for your ML/AI projects at https://www.kaggle.com/.

you will have to create an account first.

Answer (score 0):

**Sites and resources for open data**

Luckily for data analysts, there are lots of trustworthy sites and resources available for open data. It is important to remember that even reputable data needs to be constantly evaluated, but these websites are a useful starting point:

1. [U.S. government data site](https://www.data.gov/)
2. [U.S. Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/data.html)
3. [Open Data Network](https://www.opendatanetwork.com/)
4. [Google Cloud Public Datasets](https://cloud.google.com/public-datasets) (Data already loaded into BigQuery)
5. [Dataset Search](https://datasetsearch.research.google.com/): The Dataset Search is a search engine designed specifically for data sets;
6. [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/)
7. [Global Health Observatory data](https://www.who.int/data/collections)
8. [The Cancer Imaging Archive (TCIA) dataset](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/resources/public-datasets/tcia)
9. [1000 Genomes](https://cloud.google.com/life-sciences/docs/resources/public-datasets/1000-genomes)
10. [National Climatic Data Center](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/products)
11. [NOAA Public Dataset Gallery](https://www.climate.gov/maps-data/datasets)
12. [UNICEF State of the World’s Children](https://data.unicef.org/resources/dataset/sowc-2019-statistical-tables/)
13. [CPS Labor Force Statistics](https://www.bls.gov/cps/tables.htm)
14. [The Stanford Open Policing Project](https://openpolicing.stanford.edu/)